# ASP.NET page life cycle and control level events

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to brush up my knowledge and know better about the page life cycle and about the control level events in ASP.NET. While doing so, I came across few things that I am not able to understand well.

1. One of the page life cycle event methods OnSaveStateComplete, looks to be the last method before the page rendering is started, any changes to the page or control's properties done in this method can take place but won't be persisted through next page postback according to the docs.
   However, when I set the text to a textbox on this event method, it was set and restored on the next postback as well. Am I missing something here? I feel it discrepant to what has been stated in the docs.
2. If there are two dropdown lists on the page. Both are assigned with a SQLdatasource each, the second dropdown takes a parameter which is the value of the first dropdown. Everything is created and assigned inside .aspx page. In this case, OnDataBound event method of the second dropdown is fired twice initially. I never came across such a strange behavior. While if the SQLDataSource is created dynamically(programmatically inside .aspx.cs file), it works as expected(gets called only once).
3. Again, with the dropdownlists (while AutoPostBack=false), OnSelectedIndexChanged event method doesn't seem to be fired when the indexes are changed programmatically until in OnSaveStateComplete event method. When indexes of the dropdownlists are changed in OnSaveStateComplete method, OnSelectedIndexChanged event method seems to get fired on the next postback.

I have already worked on ASP.NET. Since it's been a little longer now, I am trying to look into the details again.

I appreciate if I could know whether something's wrong with my understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> any changes to the page or control's properties done in this method can take place but won't be persisted through next page postback.

Does it say changes to controls, or changes to viewstate?
(There is a difference here between changing a text box and changing view state).

The fact of view state not being updated at that point in time?

It actually does not matter in the case of a textbox, does it?

Ask the following questions:

As the user types into a text box, say “Hello”, does view state change at that point in time?
Nope!!!

If you run some JavaScript code on the page and change the text box? Does view state change at that point in time?
Nope!!!

However, any and all changes made in those controls? Well, on post-back THEY ARE transferred back to view state for that given control.

So, while changing controls in that event does not update view state?
It kind of does not matter in the context of a textbox. Any and all changes to those controls (typed in by the user, or made by JavaScript), OR IN THIS case in that event?

The control still been updated. The fact that view state not been updated yet?
Well, kind of moot, since WHEN your post-back occurs, then view state will be updated anyway, right?

If you want to see this effect better, try shoving some value directly into view state in that code. You see on post-back, the view state value does not persist, or will not have been changed.

e.g., this code:

```
 viewstate[“MyZoo”] = “this is zoo”;
```

Now, in above, as the documentation states, the above change will not persist, and if you check on post-backs, the above value will not exist.

Thus in your example use case of a text box it not really going to matter for the most part.

On post-back anything typed by the user, changed client-side JavaScript, or even your code that changes the textbox?

The current existing value of that text box will in ALL of the above cases be transferred back into view state on post-back.

> OnDataBound event method of the second dropdown is fired twice initially. I never came across such a strange behavior.

Well, the above depends on your code behind. If you have some stray page. bind() event, then it probably will trigger more then once. And if you re-bind the combo box, then again, your code to re-bind will run and the page automatic code to "try" and bind will also fire.

The simple matter is dropping SQL data sources on a web page?

They tend to be poor at best. It's ok for the first few weeks after you finished the HTML 101 for dummies book.

However, once you graduate beyond the training wheels, and start doing things more advanced like cascading combo boxes?

Well, that is about the SAME time you would do VERY well to drop using of SQL data sources in the page markup. Those SQL page based data sources are great for some simple wizard stuff. The instant you want more as a serious developer?

Well, that’s the same time you will start avoiding those “in page” SQL data sources.

The problems with SQL data sources in markup are many.

So, when do they fire, and who’s going to control when and how they bind to the control(s) in question?

In fact, your question quite much validates my whole point!!! You in effect lose much control when such automatic data binding occurs. You asking the web page to "manage" the data binding for you.

The result is difficulty controlling when those SQL data sources are used and trigger.

I “assume” that on very first page load (IsPostBack = False), then those SQL data sources run, and are triggered. On subsequent post-backs, those SQL data sources don’t in general run.

However, you can start hacking away at code, introduce some page.bind() or control.bind() in code behind say to cascade.

At this point, now you now chasing a dog’s tail so to speak. You now have your code and the markup page code both trying to trigger and bind controls for you.

This fast becomes a mess of epic proportions.

The simple matter?

If you want some cascading combo boxes, then toss out the wanker training wheels, and write + build the data source and setup this up in code behind.

You not only be glad you did, but then you get 100% complete control over such data binding, and when they run and trigger.

> OnSelectedIndexChanged event method doesn't seem to be fired when the indexes are changed programmatically

They don’t trigger other events and never did in web land.

In desktop land?
Yes, change(s) to controls will cause control events to trigger and run.

However, in web land a change of text in a text box, or change of a combo box (index) in code?

They don’t trigger events associated with that control in web land, and they never did.

Code behind changing a combo box index does not trigger any events for that control.

However, ANY code behind that changes the index of that drop down? All code behind at that instant in time will see/know/use/have/enjoy use of that newly updated value (such as selected index).

Code behind changes to controls thus don't trigger their associated events.

So, if I want to cascade 2 combo boxes?

Let’s say I will select a city, and then cascade the second combo box to display hotels for that city.

So, my markup would be this:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            <h3>Select City</h3>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="200px"
                AutoPostBack="true"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
            <h3>Select Hotel</h3>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server" Width="200px" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

Code behind this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCityCbo();
    }

    void LoadCityCbo()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = 
            new SqlCommand("Select City FROM City ORDER BY City");
        General.Cbo(cboCity, cmd, "", "City", "Select City");
    }

    protected void cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // cascade
        SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ID, HotelName
                           FROM tblhotelsA WHERE City = @City
                           ORDER BY HotelName");

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCity.SelectedItem.Text;
        General.Cbo(cboHotels, cmd, "ID", "HotelName", "Select Hotel");
    }
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Now, over time, we of course build up a library of re-usable code.

So, in my global wide "general" module, I have these 2 helper routines.

```
    public static void Cbo(DropDownList ddl,
                        SqlCommand cmd,
                        string sValue, string sText,
                        string sPrompt)
    {
        ddl.DataValueField = sValue;
        ddl.DataTextField = sText;
        ddl.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmd);
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, sPrompt);
    }

public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

As you can see, dead simple, and we 100% eliminate the “maybe” and the “perhaps” as to when the data binding triggers for such controls.

SQL data sources are an easy approach and often generated by “easy to use” wizards. They allow those new to asp.net to get data into a web page with great ease.

However, just like training wheels on a bicycle?

Once you get the hang of riding that bicycle, or using asp.net?
Well, then you dump those training wheels rather fast, and you also wind up dumping those messy, and VERY difficult to work with SQL data sources on a web page.

SQL data sources in the markup results in loss of the “when” such data sources will trigger.

And SQL data sources in markup are hard to read, hard to maintain, and hard to change in regards to having optional or extra parameters.

The above sample posted code is dead simple, easy to read, easy to change, and 100% eliminates all issues of when such code will run.

And note how clean and simple the markup is.

SQL data sources in a web page markup are ok when you have something simple, but EVEN then, over time as you want to update code, maintain code, add new features? Then those SQL data sources collapse like a big house of cards, and don’t handle changes and enhancements to code over time.

This advice includes when dealing with 2 simple cascading combo boxes.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to explain the details.  About the first question, as you said if docs say about the changes in control or the viewstate in OnSavestateComplete method. Docs actually state about the changes with page and the controls won't be persisted. I have this link as well where it has been stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)). I have already checked all the page life cycle events for the controls and viewstate that how it works.

Comment: Viewstate isn't persisted across the postback if changed in OnSaveStateComplete, but the control properties are. This might not seem to be something to worry but even about the dropdownlist, it also fires OnSelectedIndexChanged event when index is changed programmtically but only in OnSaveStateComplete method, never if changed in other methods. This behavior to work in this way with OnSaveStateComplete drew my attention and I guess it might be good to know how something works well.

Comment: Well, again, context matters here. I mean, if you in that SaveState event change the combo index, but the in client side change it back to what it was before, then the index changed event will not fire. The context was that in code behind, WHEN you change that cbo index, the event does not run nor trigger at THAT point in time like it does in desktop land. In other words, sure, even changing a text box (with a text changed event) will trigger on post-back. So, in fact that effect you seeing does mean that the events for the control trigger - but they don't at time of change in code behind.

Comment: And this begs the whole question as to why one is using OnSaveStaeComplete event anyway? I mean, we could say that any control with events attached to it will trigger AFTER view state been saved. However, that has a different meaning and context then when the control is changed, then the event triggers at that point in time. So, context matters here. As a general rule, control events don't trigger when changed by code behind (at that point in time). However, ANY control with events changed after view state will have its event(s) run/trigger on next post back - and this is not a surprise.

Comment: Viewstate is used to test/check if that control changed for text box or a combo box. In general, such control events don't run when changed by code behind. However controls changed AFTER viewstate been set? Then yes on next post back, the event(s) attached to that control will run, and this effect is not limited to a combo box, but for any control with events attached.  So, as a "general" statement? Control events don't trigger when changed by code behind, but the exception is changes from code (client or server side) AFTER viewstate been set does trigger those events, but on next post-back